# Fujitsu laptop and numlock with docking station

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard

I use a Fujitsu laptop Lifebook S762 with a full keyboard without numeric keypad. When I press a Fn key which a numlock some standard keys start to work like part of the numeric keyboard. E.g. when I press J, the keyboard enters 1, K will enter 2 and so on.

I use a docking station with attached standard USB keyboard. When I attach the notebook, I turn the numlock on so I can use its numeric keyboard. But this state is preserved when I unplug the notebook from the docking station so pressing K will enter 2. This is really annoying and even dangerous when I need to enter the password (I have already blocked my account few times).

I seek for a solution how to

- turn on the numlock when I dock the notebook
- turn off the numlock when I undock the notebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BIOS, set the `Advanced (menu) -> Numlock` option to `On/Padlock Off`.

With this setting, accessing the laptop number pad will ALWAYS require the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

Comment: Great! I have not been aware of such settings.